# twisted: Failure vs. Error

Tags: python, exception, twisted

When should I use a `twisted.python.failure.Failure`, and when should I use something like `twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone`? Or should I do `twisted.python.failure.Failure(twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone)`, and if so, in what casese should I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `Failure` represents an exception and a traceback (often different from the current stack trace).  You should use `Failure` when you are constructing an asynchronous exception.  So, when you're going to fire a `Deferred` with an error, or when you're going to call a method like `IProtocol.connectionLost` or `ClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed`.  This is because in such cases, you want the ability to associate a different stack trace with the exception than the current stack trace.

You shouldn't use `Failure(ConnectionDone)` because the correct one-argument invocation of `Failure` accepts an exception instance, not an exception class.  So, instead, use `Failure(ConnectionDone())`.  You can also use the zero-argument form to create a new `Failure`: `Failure()`.  This only works when there is a "current" exception, eg in the suite of an `except` statement.  It constructs the `Failure` using that current exception, as well as its traceback.

You can also construct a `Failure` with three-arguments, an exception class, instance, and traceback.  This is most commonly done using the return value of `sys.exc_info()`.

When you just want to raise an exception, you don't need to create a `Failure`.  Just do what you'd normally do in a Python program to raise an exception: `raise SomeException(...)`.